# Turn on anonymous access in SharePoint2010 web application using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, powershell

I try to use the [Set-SPWebApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607554.aspx) to turn on anonymous access in SharePoint2010 web application using PowerShell, however it give me the following error (see the screenshot [here](http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6232/6274350959_a7b22c0397.jpg)):

## Add SharePoint snappin

> Add-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction
>   SilentlyContinue
>
> $app = Get-SPWebApplication http://ybbest/ Set-SPwebApplication
>   -Identity $app -AllowAnonymousAccess:$True -Zone Default
>
> *Set-SPWebApplication : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AllowAnonymousAccess'. At
>   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\5fa9c881-a962-44fa-8edc-4b5e4c4bb8d1.ps1:6
>   char:59
>   + Set-SPwebApplication -Identity $app -AllowAnonymousAccess: <<<< $True -Zone Default
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-SPWebApplication], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletSetWebApplication*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell errors can be deceptive, but for once this one is quite clear: That switch parameter only exists for `new-SPWebApplication` not `set-SPWebApplication` hence the error.

You can set it afterwards too, but then you need to get an instance of the `SPWindowsAuthenticationProvider`

Remember to also set AnonymousState for each SPSite that must run anonymously.

More info and script samples [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brporter/archive/2010/06/02/stupid-sharepoint-powershell-tricks-part-i.aspx).